# Why is textread not recommended according to documentation?

Tags: matlab

The [documentation of `textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html?refresh=true) says that `textread` is not recommended for usage, and to prefer `textscan` instead.

However, I prefer textread, because I can do in a single line of code, what would take me several lines of code with textscan (I read a matrix from a text file).

```
results_matrix = textread(results_txt_fullfname,'', 'delimiter',' ');
```

Can someone explain why should I prefer `textscan` over `textread` in my case?

Comment: It really depends on the case. It appears to me that you should also consider `dlmread` and `importdata` for reading full files. `textscan` is rather used for the evluation of single lines.

Comment: `textscan` is a more powerful function and likely faster. It works very well for reading multiple lines or big files.